# Emacs paste doesnt work

Tags: linux, bash, emacs, ide, elisp

When I want to paste some text in to emacs (running in windows+cygwin+console mode emacs)
I have to issue a
    M-x xterm-mouse-mode
command to make it work. And to go about doing the regular
things I have to switch it off.

What is a better solution?

Comment: Pretty broad question. [Native Windows builds of Emacs](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/windows/) do not suffer from this problem. Are you using Cygwin + console-mode Emacs for any particular reason?

Comment: If you absolutely *have to* use Cygwin and console-mode Emacs, you could (a) set up a key binding for toggling `xterm-mouse-mode` to speed things up, or (b) check if your *terminal* (`xterm`) has a default key binding for pasting content and simply use that.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC when in xterm-mouse-mode, you can paste with shift+middle-button.

Comment: I don't think OP has a problem with pasting in `xterm-mouse-mode` but rather wants to get around having to switch to that mode (or at least make the process of switching faster)...

Comment: My impression is the reverse: he uses `M-x xterm-mouse-mode` to exit that mode.  When in xterm-mouse-mode, clicks get passed to Emacs, so a "middle click" doesn't paste the clipboard or selection but instead it does a `yank` which has no access to the clipboar or selection.  The question is indeed not precise enough to know for sure, but I can't think of any reason why enabling xterm-mouse-mode would help doing a paste.